# cant see dynamically added <ul> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, ruby-on-rails-3.2

in my rails application ,

i was making an ajax call , and from the json response i am making the check box tree

the checkboxes display fine on the view page after the ajax call ,

but when i try to see the page source , the elements added dynamically are not visible in the page source code by the browser , i can only see the source code elements before adding the dynamic contents

Can anybody please tell me , Am I doing something wrong or is it some browser property ro behave so ??

my ajax response function to add the dynamic elements

```
success: function(data) 
                    {
                        jQuery("#gradeContent").css("display","block");
                        var s=[]
                        jQuery("#gradeContent123").append('data');
                        jQuery("#gradeContent").append('<ul id="gradeContent_ul" class="ui-widget-daredevel-checkboxTree ui-widget ui-widget-content">')
                        jQuery.each(data, function(k,v) 
                        {
                            jQuery("#gradeContent").append('<li><input type="checkbox" name="category" id="category"/><span>'+k+'</span><ul>');

                            jQuery.each(v,function(k1,v1)
                            {
                                jQuery("#gradeContent").append('<li><input type="checkbox"/><span>'+v1+'</span></li>');
                            });


                            jQuery("#gradeContent").append('</ul></li><br/>');
                        });
                        jQuery("#gradeContent").append('</ul>');

                        jQuery('#gradeContent_ul').checkboxTree();

                    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes , it is browser' property and natural behavior. "View Source" only shows you the initial html code that came from server when page was firstly loaded.

Comment: so is there any way to see the dom structure created after dynamic content addition

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid use developper tools included with the browser, or install an addon (e.g. Firebug for Firefox). For example, in Firefox : you can access the Inspector by right-clicking on a HTML item and select "Inspect Element". This will display the current state of the DOM.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Of course , see "nnnnnn" answer for more details

Answer (score 3):

> *" the elements added dynamically are not visible in the page source code by the browser"*

This is normal and correct behaviour.

To view the current version of the DOM including any dynamic addition/deletion/update use the browser's debug tools, which you can open with F12 in Chrome or IE, and ctrl-shift-i in FF, or right-click on a specific element on the page and choose "Inspect Element" (or your browser's equivalent option). The dev tools will also let you see the CSS chain applicable to any given element, and event handlers, etc.